# Override `cd` or other builtin functions more than once

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

Say I have this bash function:

```
cd(){
 builtin cd "$@"
 echo "do my own thing"
}
```

the problem is that if I override `cd` in another place, only 1 override will count, any other override will be overwritten by the latest sourced function!

Is there a way to have multiple `cd` functions and for them to all be called?

I am thinking something like this:

```
alias prev_cd="cd";

cd(){
   prev_cd  
   echo "do my own thing"
}
```

but I doubt that's quite right..**the problem** with the `prev_cd` solution is that it will result in an infinite loop. Where prev_cd calls my cd function, and vice versa. **I only want prev_cd to be defined as cd definitions outside of this file..**

One trick I can use is I can find the file that the cd function is located in using:

```
shopt -s extdebug
declare -F cd
shopt -u extdebug
```

if I have already overridden the `cd` command, I can call `unset -f cd`?

It looks like RVM (Ruby Version Manager) overrides `cd`:

> cd 14 /Users/alexamil/.rvm/scripts/cd

so I don't want to mess up previous overrides of `cd`..so I only want to override `cd` if I don't mess up the previous overrides...

Comment: @Vlastimil do you understand the question? is it not clear?

Comment: if the question is not clear, perhaps this makes it clearer: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4373

Comment: Specifically on RVM, its [definition of `cd`](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/cd#L14) is to call `__zsh_like_cd cd` and that function `__zsh_like_cd` will be in your environment... So maybe just using that in your own redefinition of `cd` might be OK... It relies on RVM not changing the rules, but might be good enough... But see below for a more general answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the body of the `cd` definition into a new function with the `prev_cd` name. Use `declare -f cd` to get that definition and then `eval` to redefine that.

```
definition_prev_cd="prev_$(declare -f cd)"
eval "${definition_prev_cd}"
unset definition_prev_cd  # clean up, no reason to leave this string around

cd () {
   prev_cd "$@"
   echo "do my own thing"
}
```

You could add some checks or create a generic function to copy arbitrary functions, but this should be enough to get you to solve the problem you described...

Comment: thanks, can I use `export -f prev_cd` here?

Comment: if I try that, I get: `bash: export: prev_cd: not a function`

Comment: yeah looks like if this is sourced more than once, then `declare -f cd` will point to the new definition, so I have to check if it's been sourced already.

Comment: Yes, you need to repeat this procedure if `cd` (from RVM) gets redefined... That will overwrite your definition.