# Infinite loop? Seemingly caused by innocuous code

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this bash function:

```
botch_get_prev_cd(){
    local dr=$(declare -f cd);
    local dr_trimmed="$(tr -d "$dr")"

    if [[ "$dr_trimmed" != *"run_botch"* ]]; then
        definition_prev_cd="prev_$dr"
        echo "$definition_prev_cd";
        eval "${definition_prev_cd}"
        unset definition_prev_cd  # clean up, no reason to leave this string around
        export -f prev_cd
    fi
}
```

when I call it, my routine freezes, appears like it's just going into an infinite loop.

When I change my code to this, it works:

```
botch_get_prev_cd(){
    local dr=$(declare -f cd);

    if [[ "$dr" != *"run_botch"* ]]; then
        definition_prev_cd="prev_$dr"
        echo "$definition_prev_cd";
        eval "${definition_prev_cd}"
        unset definition_prev_cd  # clean up, no reason to leave this string around
        export -f prev_cd
    fi
}
```

so maybe I don't need to trim the whitespace to check for matching characters? I hope so, because the first function doesn't seem to work, not sure why it seems to go into an infinite loop..

Comment: What does the function do?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with [this question about overriding `cd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441203/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt yessir, see Filipe's answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441203/override-cd-or-other-builtin-functions-more-than-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t an infinite loop, it’s

```
tr -d "$dr"
```

waiting for input.

I’m not sure exactly what you’re trying to do there; if you want to use `tr` to delete characters from a value stored in a variable, you need to give it the value:

```
tr -d " " <<<"$dr"
```

would delete all spaces from the value stored in `dr`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is this line

```
local dr_trimmed="$(tr -d "$dr")"
```

I assume that `$dr` is a range of characters for `tr` to delete from *stdin*, but you have forgotten to provide `tr` with any data to process. So it's sitting there waiting for some.